# Exit/suspend APP Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

when press return button in my smartphone I think that my app is closed because after that when I access again, my APP show login page again, is it possible suspend my APP and no close?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

Install the below plugin:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-appminimize.git
```

Override the back button action to minimize the app:

```
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
declare var window;
export class SamplePage {
  backButton;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform
  ){}
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.backButton = this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(()=>{
       window.plugins.appMinimize.minimize();
    });
  }
  ionViewCanLeave(): boolean{
    this.backButton();
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply me Jai, but I would like that return button minimize my APP onlywhen Im in the main page. If I put this code in my mainPage.html It affects all my pages. Do you know how can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited the answer to register the back button action when the view enters and then remove it when it is about to leave.

Comment: Thanks Jai! "backButton;" is "declare var backButton;" no?
Other question, I have this error "Error TS1005: ';' expected."
Do you know how to solve it? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I've corrected my example, the `backButton` variable should be declared inside the class.

Comment: OK! yes, is correct but I continue with the error: "Error TS1005: ';' expected." Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: This might help [TypeScript errors after update to 2.0.0-alpha.8-1](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1173)